# What is this MySQL / MariaDB syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mariadb

I found this syntax for a timestamped field in a database table:

```
TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

What is the meaning of the first `NULL` after Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be in a `create table` syntax.

The first `NULL` simply means that the column allows NULL values.  It is the opposite of `NOT NULL`.

This is an optional keyword, because when `NOT NULL` is not specified, the column can accept `NULL`s.  However, for those who like to be specific, columns can be expressly declared that they allow `NULL` values.

Comment: oh gosh! I guess I was brain afk there ^^ thanks :) I will accept your answer as soon as I can.